# Google Sheets how to multiply two lists together in two columns

Tags: google-sheets

I have a list of colors in column A (it could be A2:A)

| A1 | Colors |
| --- | --- |
| A2 | Red |
| A3 | Blue |
| A4 | Orange |

And I have types in column B (it could be as long as B2:B)

| B1 | Types |
| --- | --- |
| B2 | Apple |
| B3 | Banana |
| B4 | Kiwi |

now how can I make this list by multiply the above two lists:

|  | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Colors | Types |
| - | ------- | ------- |
| 2 | Red | Apple |
| 3 | Red | Banana |
| 4 | Red | Kiwi |
| 5 | Blue | Apple |
| 6 | Blue | Banana |
| 7 | Blue | Kiwi |
| 8 | Orange | Apple |
| 9 | Orange | Banana |
| 10 | Orange | Kiwi |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following formula in F1 creates the required table given the source in A1:B4 using a cross-join:

```
=arrayformula({A1:B1;split(flatten(A2:A4&"|"&transpose(B2:B4)),"|")})
```